# Perl - get first "word" from input string

Tags: perl, string, regex

I am trying to write a Perl program that reads in lines from a text file, and, for each line, extract the first "word" from the line, and perform a different action based on the string that gets returned.

The main loop looks like this:

```
while(<AXM60FILE>) {

   $inputline = $_;

   ($start) = ($inputline =~ /\A(.*?) /);

perform something, based on the value of string in $start

}
```

The input file is actually a parameter file, with the parameter_name and parameter_value, separated by a colon (":").  There can be spaces or tabs before or after the colon.

So, the file looks (for example) like the following:

> param1: xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   param2 :xxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   param3 : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   param4:xxxxxxxxxxxxx

That "($start) = ($inputline =~ /\A(.*?) /);" works ok for the "param2" example and the "param3" example where the 1st word is terminated by a blank/space, but how can I handle the "param1" and "param4" situations, where the parameter_name is followed immediately by the colon?

Also, what about if the "whitespace" is a tab or tabs, instead of blank/space character?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Define ‘word’: English-language word, program identifier, whitespace-bounded chunk of non-whitespace, alphabetics, alphanumerics, etc.

Answer (score 8):

This will cover all of your cases and then some:

```
my ($key, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $inputline, 2;
```

(Or, in English, split `$inputline` into a maximum of two elements separated by any amount of whitespace, a colon and any amount of whitespace.)

Answer (score 6):

```
($start) = $inputline =~ /\A([^:\s]+)/;
```

This will match anything except whitespace and `:` at the beginning of the line.
Or using `split`:

```
($start) = split /[:\s]+/, $inputline, 2;
```

Comment: Eugene,  I've been doing more testing using your 1st suggestion, and wanted to confirm: By 'whitespace', are tab chars included?  Also, can you explain how that regex you used works, briefly?  Jim

Comment: Hi,  I guess what I'm kind of unclear about is having both the \A, which is for the beginning of string, and the caret ^, whumich I thought was for an anchor.  Isn't using both redundant?  Jim

Comment: @user555303: see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html): `\s` matches a whitespace character, the set `[\ \t\r\n\f]` and others. The special character `^` in the first position of a character class denotes a negated character class, which matches any character but those in the brackets.